# Asymptotic value of an integral related to distances in a unit n-ball

Tags: asymptotics, distance, range

In trying to find out  the pdf of  the range $T$ of  euclidean distances of $m$ randomly and uniformly chosen points  from the origin in an $n$-dimensional unit ball, I have obtained the following :
$$ f(t)=m^2.n(n-1)\int_0^{1-t} u^{m-1}(u+t)^{m-1}[(u+t)^m-u^m]^{n-2}du.$$
From the geometry of the n-dimensional ball, it is intuitively expected that the average range and variance should approach zero.That requires computing the integrals:
$$E(T)=\int_0^1tf(t)dt  $$ and
$$E(T^2)=\int_0^1t^2f(t)dt.$$
How do I evaluate the above integrals in, say, Mathematica; and **is it possible to find the analytical expressions for them in the cases when both $m,n$ approach infinity?**

Comment: You can compute $f(t)$ explicitly using the binomial theorem, since we know how to integrate powers of $u$. Then you can compute the expectations explicitly, since we know how to integrate powers of $t$.

Comment: How do i input $f(t)$ in Mathematica and compute the integrals for diff values of m and n and asymptotic case when m and n approach infinity?I mean I don't know the syntax.I would b obliged if you could help

Comment: Why use Mathematica when you can do it yourself, on paper? Use the formulas you learned in calculus.

Comment: This integral does not look like a correct solution to the stated problem.  I have to guess, because its relationship to the set of $m(m-1)/2$ mutual distances is obscure, but it has a form that suggests you might have assumed the Euclidean distances are *iid* and uniform--but neither is the case.  It wouldn't be worth evaluating this integral until you have confirmed it really does solve your problem!

Comment: I am considering the distances of $m$ points from origin and considering their range.Those distances   have a well defined pdf $p(r)=mr^{m-1}$

Comment: By definition, all points on the sphere have a *constant* distance to the origin.  This contradiction between your stated situation and your formulas is the reason why we need clarification of the problem.

Comment: These are points in the ball ,not on the ball

Comment: In your post you use the term "sphere," not ball!  If you do mean the ball, then your formulas are incorrect, because they are based on assuming the distances have uniform distributions, but that is the case only for $n=1.$

Comment: I am not assuming they are uniform,see my expression for the pdf $p(r)$ above in the comment

Comment: Thanks--I missed that comment.  Because (1) the part of the question about Mathematica is off-topic here and (2) the asymptotic part is definitely on topic, let's focus on (2).  The problem is that the answer to (2) depends on precisely *how* $(m,n)$ increase.  When $m$ (the number of points) increases much faster than $n$ (the dimension), the range must approach $1$ almost surely.  For slow rates of increase the range will approach $0$ almost surely.  What exactly is your situation? Or do you need to cover all possibilities?  If so, please edit your question to so indicate.

Comment: Could it be that you switched the $m$ and $n$ in this expression $$f(t)=m^2.n(n-1)\int_0^{1-t} u^{m-1}(u+t)^{m-1}[(u+t)^m-u^m]^{n-2}du$$ which should be  $$f(t)\propto n(n-1)\int_0^{1-t} g(u) \cdot g(u+t)  [G(u+t)-G(u)]^{m-2}du$$ with $g$ and $G$ the pdf and cdf of a single point.

Comment: yes indeed....there is standard formula for computing the range of a iid random variables.My thing immediately follows from there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This question is interesting because within its analysis lies a precise, quantified statement of the "curse of dimensionality."**

In $n$ dimensions, the volume of a region scaled by a factor $r \ge 0$ is multiplied by $r^n.$  Since the proportion of points in a unit ball $B^n$ at a distance $r$ from its origin are those within a ball of radius $r,$ which is the unit ball scaled by a factor of $r,$ the chance that a uniformly chosen point within the unit ball is within distance $r$ of its origin is

$$F(r) = r^n,\quad 0 \le r \le 1.$$

The question concerns the distribution of the range of $m$ independently chosen uniform points in $B^n$ as both $m$ and the dimension $n$ grow large.  **It models what can happen in datasets of $m$ observations having $n$ factors where both $n$ and $m$ are large.**

To study this, let's first look separately at the distributions of the largest and smallest distances.

#### The maximum

Let $Y$ be the largest of $m$ such distances. The chance $Y$ does not exceed a given value $r \le 1$ is the chance that all $m$ distances are $r$ or less, whence

$$F_Y(r) = \Pr(Y\le r) = F(r)^m = r^{mn},\quad 0 \le r \le 1.$$

As $m$ and $n$ grow large, this obviously converges to $0$ for any fixed $r\lt 1.$  Thus, **the limiting distribution of the maximum is $1:$**

> As either the number of points or the dimension of the space they are in grow large, the largest distance almost surely approaches $1:$ that is, there is at least one point arbitrarily close to the boundary.

#### The minimum

Let $X$ be the smallest of $m$ distances to the origin in $B^n.$  Analogous reasoning establishes

$$F_X(r)=\Pr(X \le r) = 1 - \Pr(X \gt r) = 1 - (1 - F(r))^m = 1 - (1 - r^n)^m,\quad 0 \le r \le 1.$$

Setting $Z = X^n,$ this shows

$$F_Z(z) = \Pr(Z \le z) = \Pr(X \le z^{1/n}) = 1 - (1 -z)^m,\quad 0 \le z \le 1.$$

Its derivative

$$f_Z(z) = F_Z^\prime(z) = m(1-z)^{m-1} = \frac{1}{B(1,m)} z^{1-1}(1-z)^{m-1}$$

is recognizable as the density of a Beta$(1,m)$ variable.  In terms of the Beta function

$$B(a,b) = \int_0^1 x^{a-1}(1-x)^{b-1}\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\Gamma(a)\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$$

we may immediately write

$$E[X^k] = E\left[\left(Z^{1/n}\right)^k\right] = \frac{B(1+k/n, m)}{B(1, m)} = \frac{\Gamma(1+k/n)\Gamma(m+1)}{\Gamma(m+1+k/n)}$$

for any positive number $k.$

When  $n$ is sufficiently large and $k=1$ or $k=2,$ we may approximate expressions of the form $\Gamma(a + k/n)$ with the derivative

$$\Gamma(a + k/n) = \exp(\log\Gamma(a + k/n)) \approx \exp(\log(\Gamma(a)) + \psi(a) k/n)) = \Gamma(a) \exp(\psi(a)k/n).$$

where $\psi(a)$ is the derivative of $\log \Gamma$ (the [digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)).  Consequently, still for large $n,$  the crucial asymptotic approximation is

> $$E\left[X^k\right] \approx \frac{\exp(\psi(1)k/n)}{\exp(\psi(m+1)k/n)}= \exp(-H_{m+1} k/n) \approx m^{-k/n}$$

where $H_m = 1 + 1/2 + \cdots + 1/m \approx \log(m).$

This shows immediately that **there are four regimes to consider as $m$ and $n$ grow large:**

1. When $(1/n)\log(m) \to \infty,$ so that the number of points $m$ is increasing faster than the exponential of the dimension $n,$ both the expectation (for $k=1$) and second moment (for $k=2$) shrink to zero, whence the variance shrinks to zero, too.  In this case, *the minimum almost surely approaches zero.*
2. When $(1/n)\log(m) \to 0,$ so that the number of points is increasing slower than $\exp(n),$ the expectation and the second moment both converge to $1.$  This implies the variance also converges to $0$ and we conclude *the minimum almost surely approaches $1.$*
3. When $(1/n)/\log(m)$ does not converge, then neither can the expectation nor the variance of $X$ converge.  Obviously there cannot be a limiting distribution, but possibly a suitably standardized version of $X$ could converge.  This covers a lot of complicated ground, so I won't pursue this possibility further.
4. Suppose, finally, that $(1/n)/\log(m)$ converges to some value $\delta$ as $(m,n)\to(\infty,\infty).$  This implies the expectation converges to $e^{-\delta}$ and the second moment converges to $e^{-2\delta},$ whence the variance converges to $e^{-2\delta} - \left(e^{-\delta}\right)^2 = 0.$  Thus, *the distribution of the minimum distance is approaching a nonzero constant value $e^{-\delta}.$*

As $m$ grows large, the dependence between the minimum and maximum of the distances grows ever weaker.  Consequently, we can find the limiting distribution of the range by simple subtraction:

> - If $m$ and $n$ grow large in such a way that $m\gg e^n,$ the range of distances in the ball approaches $1$ in distribution.
> - If eventually $m \ll e^n,$ the range approaches $0$ in distribution and almost all distances become arbitrarily close to $1:$ nearly all the points lie near the surface of the ball.
> - When eventually $m \approx e^{n\delta}$ for some number $\delta \gt 0,$ the range approaches $1 - e^{-\delta}$ while the maximum approaches $1.$

---

**It is worth remarking on the generality of this analysis.**  The initial derivation of $F$ based on scaling applies to any region $\mathcal R$--not just a ball--that is star-shaped with respect to a point in its interior.   (This means the result of scaling the region by any factor $0\le r \le 1$ is a subset of the region itself.)  All convex regions are star-shaped with respect to any of their interior points, for instance.

The meaning of "distance" is now subtly different but useful: we say a point $x$ has a "distance" $r$ when $x$ is in the $r$-scaled version of $\mathcal R$ (with respect to its distinguished point) but $x$ is not in the $r$-scaled version for any smaller value of $r.$  The three key conclusions retain their original interpretations; in particular, in the cases where the "distances" are almost surely $1,$ the points must be almost surely near the boundary $\partial \mathcal R.$

In this sense, *balls are not special.*  The relevant geometry is that associated with dimension alone, rather than any particular domain.  This implies the analysis is quite general and applies to any dataset whatsoever, to the extent we might conceive of it as being one in a series of ever larger datasets contained with a series of domains in $\mathbb R^n$ of increasing dimensions.

Comment: ,lots of thanks for your wonderful response and taking time to put it so elegantly.One thing that I am struggling with is :is it possible to somehow derive the same conclusions from the integral itself ,or even to backtest them by assuming various limiting  relations  between them?

Comment: I am sure that's possible, as a mathematical exercise.  Because my analysis explicitly evaluates two closely related integrals, it might be fruitful to use them to approximate the integral for the range.